# Using 'controller as' with the ui-router isn't working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have the following state setup for a page using an abstract state and the controller as syntax:

```
# Details page route
.state 'title', 
  url: '/title',
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view/>',
.state 'title.show', 
  url: '/:titleId',
  templateUrl: 'title/show.html'
  controller: 'Title as t'
```

For the purpose of this demo lets say I assign a variable to the 't' instance of the 'Title' controller and I do this inside of the Title controller function.

```
angular.module('title').controller 'Title',
 ['$state', ($state) ->
   this.name = 'Test'
```

and inside my view 'title/show.html' I attempt to print out that variable I just created to the page:

```
{{t.name}}
```

I don't see anything. But if I remove the controller our of the ui-router and onto the element that wraps the 'title/show.html' page like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Title as t">
```

Then everything works great. Has anyone come across this problem before. I have it working fine in another app so I'm still trying to figure out what might be different in this app, maybe a difference in js library versions.

Comment: Which version of `ui-router` are you using?

Answer (score 44):

**In your state configuration :**

Instead of `controller: 'Title as t'`, try :

```
controller: 'Title',
controllerAs: 't'
```

**Edit** : Just implemented a minimal app with `ui-router` and the syntax `controller: Title as t` also works, in versions 0.2.0 of `ui-router` to the most recent one as of today. I can see the `t` instance when I inspect angular scopes.

Comment: Should not be the problem considering controller: 'ctrl as ctrl' is supported by ui-router, see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers

Comment: Yep, noticed that in the doc after my post, but that might be safer to try with the old syntax (in case OP has an older version of `ui-router`)

Comment: Yea, I already tried the controllerAs but still the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out Michael P. I must have some kind of other conflict in my app thats causing this. Ill update if I figure out what.

Comment: @user823903 Did you manage to figure this out ? I have the same problem, I'm using coffescript and want to use controllerAs syntax, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Same here, super weird

Comment: Why coffescript is so cool but has problems like this(( OP did you figure out the solution?

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 13):

Your controller needs to return the value of `this` in order for the controllerAs feature to work properly. Since CoffeeScript implicitly returns the last line, you need to write:

```
return this
```

or if you are using the vm syntax and have written:

```
vm = this
```

you can write at the very end of the controller:

```
return vm
```

Comment: I am able to have it working without `return this` on angular 1.3.10
Is it documented anywhere to `return this` for controllerAs feature to work properly?

Comment: Was working with some older code of mine and had a Decorator still decorating `$scope` instead of `this` :-P Thx a bunch!

Answer (score 10):

If this helps anyone my problem came about from using templated views but specifying the controllerAs outside the views element. This took forever to figure out. Credit to this thread https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3058

** WRONG **

```
views: {'content@': { templateUrl: 'views/listing.html' }},
controller: 'ListingCtrl',
controllerAs: 'ctrl'
```

** RIGHT **

```
views: {
  'content@': { templateUrl: 'views/listing.html' },
   controller: 'ListingCtrl',
   controllerAs: 'ctrl'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasted an evening trying to figure out why it's not working :-(. Hopefully it'll be fixed in Ionic.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like these answers might be working for a lot. I came here with a different problem :

In my `UI Router` Javascript file, my `controllers` are defined like this :

```
state('groupHome', {
     url: '/groupHome',
     templateUrl: 'app/modules/group-home/groupHome.html',
     controller: 'GroupHomeController',
     controllerAs: 'groupHomeController'
```

And in my template file if I try to access the controller with the name `groupHomeController` it is not able to access.

But on the other hand when I changed my code to this :

```
state('groupHome', {
     url: '/groupHome',
     templateUrl: 'app/modules/group-home/groupHome.html',
     controller: 'GroupHomeController as groupHomeController'
```

It works perfectly fine.

Comment: it worked like a charm. but do you know the reason why `controlleras` is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `return this;` at the end of your `controller function` for the `controllerAs` syntax to work.

```
angular.module('title').controller 'Title',
 ['$state', ($state) ->
   this.name = 'Test'
   return this
```

If you are working with **`$scope`**, you'll have to `return $scope` instead.

```
angular.module('title').controller 'Title',
 ['$state','$scope', ($state, $scope) ->
   $scope.name = 'Test'
   return $scope
```

Good Luck.