# Where is the controller defined in this ui-state definition?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at an angularjs app with an UI-staterouter. The router looks like this:

```
  .state('root.one.detail.more', {
                url: '/:section',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                bindToController: true,
                templateProvider: function ($stateParams, $templateCache) {
                    return $templateCache.get($stateParams.stage + '.html');
                },.....
```

My question is: based on this codesample can you tell me what the controllerAs property refers to. It says vm but where can I find the actual controller?

Answer (score 1):

I think the "controllerAs" will define a variable that will reference your controller in application, so... acording to your code, the controller is not defined.

You may see this answer to better understand the route configuration
[Using 'controller as' with the ui-router isn't working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953289/using-controller-as-with-the-ui-router-isnt-working-as-expected)